# Javascript function doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
$("tbody").on('click', '#update', function () {
    $("#UpdateModal").modal("show");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: "/Users/GetUser?id=" + id,
        data: {
            "cusid": id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data.userName);
            var departments = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.departments));
            var duties = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.duties));
            var roles = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.roles));
            $('#UpdateModal #Id').attr('value', response.data.id);
            $('#UpdateModal #UserName').attr('value', response.data.userName);
            $('#UpdateModal #FirstName').attr('value', response.data.firstName);
            $('#UpdateModal #LastName').attr('value', response.data.lastName);
            $('#UpdateModal #Password').attr('value', response.data.password);


            $("#UpdateModal #DepartmentId option:first-child").prop("selected", "selected").text(response.data.departmentName);


            $("#UpdateModal #DutyId option:first-child").prop("selected", "selected").text(response.data.dutyName);
            $("#UpdateModal #RoleId option:first-child").prop("selected", "selected").text(response.data.roleName);

            if (response.data.isActive) {
                $("#UpdateModal #IsActive #true").prop("selected", "true")
                console.log(response.data.isActive);
            }
            else {
                $("#UpdateModal #IsActive #false").prop("selected", "false")
                console.log(response.data.isActive);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < departments.length; i++) {
                if (response.data.departmentName == departments[i].departmentName) { $("#UpdateModal #DepartmentId option:first-child").prop("selected", "selected").val(departments[i].id); }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < duties.length; i++) {
                if (response.data.dutyName == duties[i].dutyName) {
                    $("#UpdateModal #DutyId option:first-child").prop("selected", "selected").val(duties[i].id);
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
                if (response.data.roleName == roles[i].roleName) { $("#UpdateModal #RoleId option:first-child").prop("selected", "selected").text(response.data.roleName).val(roles[i].id); }
            }



        }

    });
});
```

What I want to do here is to pull the data into my update modal with API. But it can't do it. Actually it was working before but suddenly the code stopped working. Can anyone see the error?

What do I need to do for this function to work? It gets triggered when I use the same code in another view. But it never gets triggered here. Please help.

Comment: Is the "#update" element present in the DOM? Have you tried to put a `debugger;` at the beginning of the function to make sure it's not getting triggered?

Comment: if this works in another view this can only mean that 
1. Element "#update" doesn't exists; 2. your script is not loaded in that view

Comment: Do you get any console errors?  Open browser, F12, select console. load page, attempt to click on "#update".

Comment: Is your `tbody` dynamically loaded?  (or loaded after the code runs)  Try changing from `$("tbody").on` to `$(document).on` (not "best practice", but will rule out the issue, then you can find a suitable static element to attach to).  Try putting your code in a doc.ready.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

I also tried the (document).on method, but it didn't work. When I put the debugger, I saw that Javascript was not triggered. I also have the ID element. However, my code never gets triggered.

Comment: Do you mean `$("tbody").on` never gets triggered or what's inside the handler `$("#UpdateModal").modal("show");`?

Comment: on the debugger console, try query your element using $("#update") and check if it's onclick property is bound. Another choice may be binding the onclick even directly to the element using  $('#update').on('click', function() {})